# How to change position of column form responding sheet after add form item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I can add an item to a Google form and to change its position in the form by Google apps script. The corresponding column in the responding sheet is always the last column. I can manually move that column to the position I want (same position as the item in the form), but how do I move it using Google apps script?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for a script to rearrange columns linked to a form. The sheets and columns linked to a form are special, and this special nature is not something Apps Script can see. (Explanation below).

#### Alternative approach

Create another sheet, *Real* Form Data, in which the first row is filled with formulas such as

`={'Form Responses 1'!A:A}`, `={'Form Responses 1'!C:C}`, `={'Form Responses 1'!B:B}`

in whatever order you wish. These formulas can be manipulated by a script in any way you want, with `setFormula(s)` methods. You can hide the original sheet with form data, and work only with this new one, which has the desired order of columns.

#### Explanation

There is no script method for "moving" the way we move rows and columns in the interface. Their surrogates, described in [Moving a column in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21145080), are

1. Insert a column, copy values there, delete the original.
2. Take values of the entire sheet, rearrange them script-side, then write back.

Method 1 doesn't work for form data because the new column wouldn't be linked to the form (and the original column can't be deleted).

Method 2 doesn't work because changing the values in columns doesn't affect their invisible link to the form: it will still send data in the same way as it did.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear answer! I will follow your alternative approach. Still i think it is strange. Manually you can move the column that is related to a form! So it is possible, however there is no script available...Perhaps in future...?